# Ajax works more than one after one tap

Tags: jquery, ajax, jquery-mobile

I have a problem about my AJAX Call. I have a list with buttons that have"showuserinfo" classes and when I tap on showuserinfo and go back and tap again, the AJAX call works more than once. If I tap showuserinfo,go back and tap again, the AJAX Call works twice. If I do it repeatedly, the AJAX Call runs repeatedly as well. Here is my code:

```
 $('.showuserinfo').live('tap', function(event){
        $.mobile.loading('show');
        var user_id = $(this).children().find('a').attr('id');
        //$('#showprofile').page('destroy').page();
        $('#showprofileImage img').remove();
        $('#showprofileContent div').remove();
        $( document ).delegate("#showprofile", "pagebeforeshow", function() {
         $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "http://fitness.desigyn.com/func/phonegapApi.php",
            data: { operation: "getSpecificProfile", requested: user_id ,username: 'kurekcifuat', password: '123456' },
            async : false,
            cache : false,
            }).done(function( msg ) {
                if(msg == "fail")
                {
                    alert('error');
                }
                else{
                    var obj = $.parseJSON(msg);
                        alert(msg); // Debugging and that code works more than once
                    $('#showprofileImage img').remove();
                    $('#showprofileContent div').remove();
                    $('#showprofileImage').append('<img class="otheruserpic" style="height:120px !important; width:120px !important;" src="' + obj["0"].picture + '"/>');
                    $('#showprofileContent').append('<div class="otheruserinfo"><b>Username: </b><span>' + obj["0"].username + '</span></div><div><b>Name: </b><span>' + obj["0"].name + '</span></div><div><b>Age: </b><span>' + obj["0"].age + '</span></div><div><b>Gender: </b><span>' + obj["0"].gender + '</span></div>');
                }
            });
            $.mobile.loading('hide');
         });

        });
```

Any suggestions?
Cheers.

Comment: `.live()` is no longer used, use `.on` instead. what version of jQ and jQM are you using?

Comment: I'm using jqm version 1.2.0 and I tried .on but it did not worked as expected.

Comment: is `$('.showuserinfo').live('tap', function(event){` in a place that is called more than once as thats what it sounds like is happening.

Comment: I can not end the ajax call. The function must be on that place exactly.

Comment: I didnt ask anything about your ajax call.. i asked if where you have that code (i assume its in some function, colsure, etc) is it being called more than once.

Comment: actually it is on the $(document).ready() function and does not belong to any function. I have a list of items that contains these .showuserinfo buttons and I want to load a page dynamically. but the function works more than once. By the way, I added an alert(1) code before delegate function and I does not call more than once after several taps.

Comment: you shouldn't use `.ready()` with jQM. anyway to fix this try the following: replace `.live()` with `.on()` and replace with `$( document ).delegate("#showprofile", "pagebeforeshow", function()` with `$(document).off("#showprofile", "pagebeforeshow").on("#showprofile", "pagebeforeshow", function()` it looks like its firing twice with `pagebeforeshow` event.

Comment: @Omar I tried what you suggested but it did not worked. probably .on() function is not working

Comment: `$(document).on('tap', '.showuserinfo', function(event){` try this with this as well `$(document).off("pagebeforeshow", "#showprofile").on("pagebeforeshow", "#showprofile", function () { }); `

Comment: @Omar thank man it nailed the problem.

Comment: @Omar write this as answer and I can close it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, using `.ready()` isn't recommended with jQuery Mobile. Secondly, `.live()` is replaced with `.on()`.

You Ajax request is being fired twice when `pagebeforeshow` triggers. To avoid this, do the following.

First, fix `.live()`.

```
$(document).on('tap', '.showuserinfo', function(event) { });
```

And then use the below to kill any previous bindings for `pagebeforeshow`.

```
$(document).off("pagebeforeshow", "#showprofile").on("pagebeforeshow", "#showprofile", function () { });
```

Answer (score 4):

You have a problem with multiple event binding.

Change this:

```
$('.showuserinfo').live('tap', function(event){

});
```

to this:

```
$('.showuserinfo').die('tap').live('tap', function(event){

});
```

or even better use on like this:

```
$(document).off('tap', '.showuserinfo').on('tap', '.showuserinfo' ,function(event){

});
```

Read more about multiple event binding **[here](http://www.gajotres.net/document-onpageinit-vs-document-ready/)**, search for chapter: **Prevent multiple event binding/triggering**.